# Collapse dimension when comparing model coefficients

Tags: anova, statistical-significance, model

I have a dataset that includes 2 dimensions (A, B), each of which has the same two categories (1,2).  I fit a model to the data in each of the 4 conditions and get 4 coefficients for a parameter of interest as a result including various stats about them (SE, CI, etc).  I want to determine if dimensions A or B produce significant differences in the coefficient in conditions 1 and 2, similar to what a two-way anova would do.  How can I group model coefficients together in this way so that I can compare them across each dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test the linear restriction?

Example: $y=1_A\beta_A+1_B \beta_B +\varepsilon$, where $1A,1_B$ - dummies for conditions A and B. Next, test the restriction $\beta_A-\beta_B=0$ using F-test or Wald's as usual.

Comment: I don't really know how to set this up.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: take a look at these notes [Testing Linear Restrictions on Parameters](http://jackman.stanford.edu/classes/350B/07/ftestforWeb.pdf). In your case R matrix is a vector [-1 1], and the r vector is simply [0]. Your statistical package must have a command to test the linear restrictions, such as [test](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rtest.pdf) command in Stata

Comment: I did read that already.  I'm not sure how to translate it to my problem.  I have 4 coefficients of a Gabor Fit, one for each condition, and these act as my measurements, with one measurement per condition.  So I'm not sure how to translate it directly.  Using R to do this if you have a specific example.

Comment: the long way is to run OLS, where A and B are dummies: y~A*B, i.e. with interaction. you'll get three coefficients: A, B and AB. This will cover your 4 states. Next, you run your linear restriction test on A=B as I described earlier. I don't remember how to do it in R, sorry, but it's very easy.

Comment: Alright, well I'm not able to figure out how to run a linear restriction model or, essentially devise an F test based on the stats of each coefficient.  Maybe stats packages know how to do that, but without understanding that I can't really implement it on my own.  If you can give a specific example of the calculation I can just implement it on my own.  Just make up 4 coefficients as measures, a standard error and df for reach, etc, and show me how to set up the test manually.